# Relations between complex functions satisfying a specific condition

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

What is the relation between the following two complex functions:

$$g(\theta)=\sum_n x[n]\ y[n]\ e^{in\theta}$$

and

$$f(\theta)=\sum_n \left(x[n]\pm i\sqrt{1-x[n]^2}\right)\ y[n]\ e^{in\theta}$$

where $\theta$ ranges from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and $x[n]$ is real and smaller than 1 and $y[n]$ is in general complex ? Can we find a single equation that relates the two functions ?

Comment: Is $|x[n]|<1$..?

Comment: @rlgordonma yes!

Comment: I don't know of *any* nonlinear transformation on the Fourier side that can be expressed explicitly in terms of functions. So the answer to "can we find..." is: in all likelihood, no.